# Is there a way to loop if statements targetting a specific variable from a list of objects C#

Tags: c#, foreach

In my class (Book) there is a variable (Bcopies) that indicates how many of these objects are “borrowed”
From my list (values) I already got the highest int which is to be displayed as the “most popular item”
I would like a better way to display that instead of multiple if statements for each instance of the variable in question(Bcopies)  I thought of a for-each loop but don’t know how to implement with a variable inside a list

here is my program

```
namespace Library
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Book book1 = new Book("book one", "Author one", 900, 35, 16);
            Book book2 = new Book("book two", "Author two", 240, 42, 8);
            Book book3 = new Book("book three", "Author three", 700, 23, 8);
         
            List<Book> BLibShelf = new List<Book>();
            BLibShelf.AddRange(new List<Book>() { book1, book2, book3, book4, book5, book6, book7,  book8 });

            var values = new List<int> { book1.BCopies, book2.BCopies, book3.BCopies, book4.BCopies, book5.BCopies, book6.BCopies, book7.BCopies, book8.BCopies };

            var t = values.Max();

//if statements allocating the "most popular"

if (book1.BCopies == t)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(book1);
           }
           if (book2.BCopies == t)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(book2);
           }
           if (book3.BCopies == t)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(book3);
           }
```

here is my class

```
class Book
    {
        public string title;
        public string author;
        public int pages;
        public int Libcopies;
        public int BCopies;
                     
        public Book(string nTitle, string nAuthor, int nPages, int nLcopies, int nBcopies)
        {
            title = nTitle;
            author = nAuthor;
            pages = nPages;
            Libcopies = nLcopies;
            BCopies = nBcopies;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Book Title:" + title + " |Author:" + author + " |Pages:" + pages + " |Library Copies:" + Libcopies + " |Borrowed Copies:" + BCopies;
        }
        public int TotalCopy()
        {
            
            return BCopies + BCopies;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `ArgMax` - argument (book in your case) on which we have `Max` value (`BCopies`).
You can do it with a help of *Linq* either via `MaxBy` (wants **.Net 6+**) or `Aggregate` (lower .Net versions):

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  Book mostPopular = BLibShelf
    .Aggregate((most, book) => most.BCopies > book.BCopies ? most : book);

  Console.Write($"The most popular book is {mostPopular}");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use LINQ:

```
List<Book> BLibShelf = new List<Book>
{
    new Book("book one", "Author one", 900, 35, 16),
    new Book("book two", "Author two", 240, 42, 8),
    new Book("book three", "Author three", 700, 23, 8)
};

Book mostPopularBook = BLibShelf.OrderByDescending(b => b.BCopies).First();
Console.WriteLine(mostPopularBook);
```

[Language Integrated Query (LINQ) (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET 6 you can use the new [`MaxBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0) Linq method:

```
var mostPopularBook = BLibShelf.MaxBy(b => b.BCopies);
```